# Get count of rows from LEFT JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql

Blog table

[image: T]

Comment table

[image: Comment table]

i'm trying get no of count comment at one blog and if there is no comment they return 0.i'm trying many JOIN but i'm not getting right data.

My query-

```
SELECT count(cid),     tbl_blog.blog_name,tbl_blog.bid,tbl_blog.blog_images,tbl_blog.blog_content,tbl_blog.created_date
    FROM tbl_blog
     LEFT JOIN tbl_blog_comment
    ON tbl_blog_comment.bid = tbl_blog.bid
```

Please help.

Comment: `GROUP BY tbl_blog.bid`

Comment: Where does cid belong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Count(cid) needs to be be count(TABLE.COLUMN) format.

so try:

```
count(tbl_blog_comment.cid) as countRows
```

This is because the query is running over multiple tables but - as far as I understand your question- the count is just a Column but doesn't tell  MySQL where the column is.

EDIT: This is updated to reflect comment conversation and to give a more fuller answer:

```
SELECT tbl_blog.blog_name, tbl_blog.bid, tbl_blog.blog_images, tbl_blog.blog_content, tbl_blog.created_date, COUNT(tbl_blog_comment.cid) as CountComments
    FROM tbl_blog
     LEFT JOIN tbl_blog_comment
    ON tbl_blog_comment.bid = tbl_blog.bid GROUP BY tbl_blog.bid
```

This will return the count of comments per blog, for each row of your result set, each row corresponding to each blog. The count will be returned in the array variable "CountComments"

Also credit to Mihai for the "Group By" addition.

Comment: I tried this,but they return only one blog,i want all blog with no of comment they have.

Comment: @Secure on your quoted source SQL code, that returns each table row as you've specified, be it all rows or just one, I have solved your issue with COUNT, and so on each row, there will be a value called countRow which will say how many comments for each blog.

Comment: Also - you will need to put the count at the end of the SELECT query as the count references a table that occurs AFTER the tbl_blog table.

Comment: @Secure I have updated my answer. note the two differences, and give it a try.

Comment: That's good. If it solved it, and it works ok, can you give my answer a tick? Cheers